# Connection timeout while connecting to EC2 instance(SSH) after enabling nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ssh, lets-encrypt

Everything was working fine. I could connect to my EC2 instance through SSH. Then I wanted to install let-encrypt. I was following this tutorial to install https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04. During the process of installing lets-encrypt, I install nginx and while trying to enable nginx, I got a message that I might not be able to connect to my instance through SSH anymore. I ignored the message. Now when I try to connect to my instance though SSH, I get error

```
connection timed out
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo ufw enable`?

Comment: Provide the output of `sudo ufw status`